# How to Check the URL or path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app where I have a `show` action with a form.  This `show` action uses a view that checks `if user_type == "admin"` and displays a partial accordingly.  For this `show` view, only `if user_type = admin` can access it.

Once the form is submitted, it triggers another action in the same controller (`store`).  The issue I'm having is that when there is an error with the submission, `store` renders `show` without reference to the user, so the partial doesn't appear since user_type won't equal admin (since it can't find the user).  However, since access to 'show' is protected, I'm wondering if there's a way I can check the url.

Example:
the form is on:

```
http://foo.com/bars/4/users/3
```

however, when it fails, the render url becomes:

```
http://foo.com/bars/4/users/store
```

the show.html.erb view has this:

```
<%= form_for([:bar,@user], :url => store_bar_users_path(params[:bar_id]), :html => {:name=>"users_form",:multipart => true,:class=> "standardForm"}) do |user| %>

<%= render :partial => "users/admin_options" if @user.user_type == "admin" %>
```

in the `store` action in the controller:

```
 if !@user.save
  render :action  => "show" ,:layout => 'application'
 else
```

So what I'm wondering is if I can change the conditional in:

```
<%= render :partial => "users/admin_options" if @user.user_type == "admin" %>
```

to somehow also also check the url for `store_bar_users_path`, or something like that - or perhaps the render in the `store` action is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the user type in a session variable, set when the user logs in. Then you don't have to keep loading it, and it is visible to all controllers, views, and helpers. Use this variable to determine if you want to show the partial.